# wicket 1. 6.6 spring project

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff, wicket-1.6

I am looking for a start point for my project
I want to start a project containing

1. wicket 1.6.6
2. integration to Spring
3. simple log in page (no a must)

do you know about one which will work with 1.6.6 (all the examples are 1.5 and under) and without JPA or any other built in CRUD mechanism

Comment: There is no 1.6. It's 6.6.0.

Comment: OK you are right buut it's just semantics , are u familier with 6.6.0 spring wicket example ? or can guide me to one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was using

```
  addComponentInstantiationListener(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
```

when i am using 1.6.6
now i am using

```
  getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
```

10x to all that looked for anwser ...